# Upload updated a file on Google Drive with Python using Drive API V3 does not work

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

I would not post this here but I invested hours now into understanding why the last part of my Python script does not behave as I expect it to behave reading documentation and many other posts on this topic.

What I want to achieve.

- Create project in Google Cloud Platform and enable Drive API - works
- Create OAuth credentials for Drive API - works
- Authenticate with Google Drive from Python script - works
- Download the file I want to edit with Python script - works
- Upload the modified file after edit with Python script - does not work

I am using this function from the official Google documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update

But it gives the following error:

```
    raise TypeError('Got an unexpected keyword argument "%s"' % name)
TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument "newRevision"
```

When I remove it from the function call I am getting this:

> An error occurred:
> <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/1T1dl_Z3z-FDLa7lbWib8XxgbTd5pMpIP?alt=json&uploadType=resumable returned "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.">

I do not understand why I am getting this.

Why does the official sample contain a parameter that is not supported?
Is it possible that I am using a different version of the Google Python libraries locally then they expect me to have? I just followed the official documentation again?
Is is possible that I do not have sufficient rights to update the file?

Thanks,
Andre

Comment: please edit your question and include your code we cant help you debug it if we cant see it.

Comment: Can you share the request body? In any case, looking at the error you're getting, you're trying to update a property that cannot be updated (not all properties in the File resource are writable). If you provide the request body, I could provide more details on this.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I figured it out by myself why it was not working.

If you follow the Python Google Drive Quick Onboarding you will use version 3 of their API: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python

This line defines the version:

```
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```

If you continue searching in their documentation for a functionality to update a file I ended up here in the version 2 documentation and snippets:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update

Looking here for the version 3 snippet there is none existing in their documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update

So I assumed it is still valid what they posted for version 2, but this is not the case.

I did everything now in version 2 and it is finally working.

#### Edit to add reference:

`newRevision` is a valid parameter in v2, but not in v3, so I assume that, in v3, blob uploads always create a new revision (that's what happens in v2 if this parameter is not set – default is `true`). See [Parameter differences between v2 and v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/v2-to-v3-reference#parameter_differences_between_v2_and_v3):

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|    Method    | v2 Parameter | v3 Parameter |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| files.update | newRevision  |      n/a     |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```